# Can I use atom to build Mac applications using coffee

Tags: atom-editor

Can I use atom to build Mac applications? Like real ones, with an icon and everything? I know that's probably not what it's built for, but I see that you can edit it using coffee, so I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Just don't expect anybody will care about an app that is likely to be junky. You can still use Java too. Doesn't make great native apps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your question is if you could build a MAC apps with javascript.
My answer is yes. There is several tools for your purpose. [`node-webkit`](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) is a good start for you. Besides, `atom-editor` is only text editor software that can make your app development productive and enjoyable